# Word web app force to open document with office add-in

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-word, office-addins, office365-apps

Im making a Sharepoint Application. I want to save documents in my sharepoint and open it with Word online(office online/ word web app).

When I open a document in Word online I want to force that a office add-in also starts. Here is an example:

[image: On the right is the app]

I already manage to open the documents in Word Online. But I havent manage to force the office add-in. Is this posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe it is possible to force an add-in to load automatically right now. The model is that the user must actively open it each time the document is loaded. The exception here are Content add-ins which are embedded into the document as a piece of content.

Please mark the answer as 'answered' if it answers your question.